# Correlation attack on Lagged Fibonacci Generator

Tags: attack, vigenere, ciphertext-only-attack

Say that one uses a known LFG (2 known lags $a$ & $b$, known inner state length $N$, known modulo $m$) to hide some text with a basic à la Vigenère cipher: $C_i=(P_i + {PRNG}_i) \bmod 26$.

Say that the adversary intercepts some ciphered text (not the LFG output), 
could they use it to perform a correlation attack to get the initial inner state of the LFG? And if so, how much ciphertext would be needed?

Comment: Hi Peyre and welcome. Please try and format your question to your best abilities (check the edit by clicking `edited xxx ago`). That will make us take the question more seriously and others to take this site more seriously :)